# Dictating in MS Visual C#?

Tags: c#, dictating, sound-recognition

I wanna make a text editor but its different other text editors.It will get commands from my voice.

For example ; i will say my name to microphone "Ibrahim AKGUN" .. then this program will get it and write it down like a virtual secretary :)

This is possible in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SpeechRecognizer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer(VS.85).aspx) in System.Speech.

If you handle the SpeechRecognized event the text is in `e.Result.Text`.